# Recaptcha não renderiza

Tags: jsf, primefaces, recaptcha, primefaces-3.5

Estou tentando colocar um recaptcha na minha view, mas ele não renderiza de jeito nenhum e aparece a seguinte exceção:

> Advertência: JSF1090: Caso de navegação não resolvido para o
>   componente j_idt200.

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />    
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt-BR'></script>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

            <p:layoutUnit id="centerLayoutUnit" position="center" style="top: 70px;">
                <h:form id="centerForm" >
                    <p:messages id="mensagens" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

                    <p:outputPanel id="cadastro">
                        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.renderizaCadastro}">
                            <p:wizard id="wizardForm" widgetVar="wizardForm" backLabel="Voltar" nextLabel="Próximo" showStepStatus="false"
                                      binding="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.wizardForm}" showNavBar="false">

    <!-- PARTE OCULTADA -->

                                <p:tab id="tabAnexoArquivos" title="Confirmação e Envio de Documentos">
                                    <p:panel id="anexoArquivos" header="Confirmação e Envio de Documentos">
                                        <h:outputText value="AVISO: Será enviada uma mensagem no email cadastrado 
                                                  com data de agendamento para apresentação dos documentos originais" 
                                                  style="color: #f00; font-weight: bold;"/>

                                        <br />
                                        <br />

                                        <fieldset>
                                            <legend>
                                                <h:outputLabel value="Anexar Arquivos" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                                            </legend>

                                            <p:outputPanel id="tipoDocumento">
                                                <p:outputPanel rendered="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.tipoProtocoloSelecionado != null}">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <ui:repeat value="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.obterTiposDocumentosObrigatorios()}" var="itemTipoDocumento">
                                                            <li>
                                                                <p:commandLink value="#{itemTipoDocumento.descricao}" actionListener="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.abrirAnexosTiposDocumentosObrigatorios(itemTipoDocumento)}"
                                                                    immediate="true" update="@([id$=tipoDocumento], [id$=panelTiposDocumentos])" title="Clique para anexar arquivos"/>
                                                            </li>

                                                            <ui:repeat value="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.recuperarArquivosAnexados(itemTipoDocumento)}"
                                                                       var="itemArquivoAnexado">

                                                                <li style="margin-left: 20px;">
                                                                    <h:outputText value="#{itemArquivoAnexado.nomeArquivo}" style="margin-right: 1px;"/>
                                                                    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.excluirAnexo(itemArquivoAnexado)}"
                                                                    style="margin-right: 3px;" immediate="true" update="@([id$=tipoDocumento])">
                                                                        <p:graphicImage alt="Excluir" value="../imagens/site/delete.png" />
                                                                    </p:commandLink>
                                                                </li>

                                                            </ui:repeat>
                                                        </ui:repeat>
                                                    </ul>

                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />

                                                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.renderizaMenuTodosOsTiposDocumentos}">
                                                        <h:outputLabel value="Tipo de Documento *: " style="font-weight: bold" />
                                                        <h:selectOneMenu id="tiposDocumentos" style="height: 20px; width: 200px; background-color: #fff;"
                                                                         converter="tipoDocumentoRegistroOnlineEmpresaConverter"
                                                                         required="true" requiredMessage="Tipo de Documento: Preenchimento Obrigatório"
                                                                         validator="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.validatorTeste}"
                                                                         validatorMessage="Tipo de Documento Inválido">
                                                            <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                                                            <f:selectItems value="#{tipoDocumentoController.tiposDocumentos}"
                                                                           var="tipoDocumento" itemValue="#{itemTipoDocumento}" itemLabel="#{tipoDocumento.descricao}" />
                                                            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />

                                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                    </p:outputPanel>

                                                    <br />

                                                    <p:outputPanel style="width: 300px;" rendered="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.renderizaFileUpload}">
                                                        <h:outputLabel value="Anexo de Arquivos *:" style="font-weight: bold" />

                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />

                                                        <p:fileUpload id="uploadAnexo"
                                                                      fileUploadListener="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.handleFileUpload}"
                                                                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|png|jpe?g|pdf)$/"
                                                                      sizeLimit="10000000"
                                                                      label="Escolher..."
                                                                      multiple="true"
                                                                      auto="true"
                                                                      showButtons="false"
                                                                      mode="advanced"
                                                                      uploadLabel="Enviar Arquivos"
                                                                      process="@this"
                                                                      dragDropSupport="true"
                                                                      required="true"
                                                                      invalidFileMessage="Arquivo Inválido! Anexe apenas imagem e/ou PDFs"
                                                                      invalidSizeMessage="Tamanho inválido! Tamanho máximo 10MB"
                                                                      requiredMessage="Anexe pelo menos um arquivo"
                                                                      update="tipoDocumento"/>

                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />

                                                        <p:commandButton icon="voltar" value="Voltar" update="tipoDocumento" immediate="true"
                                                                         actionListener="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.voltarAnexo()}"/>
                                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                                </p:outputPanel>
                                            </p:outputPanel>

                                        </fieldset>

                                        <br />
                                        <br />

                                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.aceitacaoTermos}"
                                                                 title="Aceito o Termo de Responsabilidade"
                                                                 validator="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.validarAceitacaoTermos}"/>

                                        <h:outputLabel value="Aceito o " style="font-weight: bold"/>

                                        <h:link target="blank" outcome="termoResponsabilidadeEmpresa" value="Termo de Responsabilidade" 
                                                style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;"/>

                                        <br />
                                        <br />

                                        <h:panelGrid style="text-align: left;margin-left: 10px;">
                                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_KEY"></div> 
                                        </h:panelGrid>

                                        <br />
                                        <br />

                                        <p:commandButton icon="adicionar" value="Enviar Cadastro"
                                                         action="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.gerarRegistro()}" />
                                    </p:panel>
                                </p:tab>
                            </p:wizard>

                            <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                                <p:commandButton value="Voltar" icon="voltar" immediate="true" actionListener="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.onBack()}"
                                                 rendered="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.renderizaBotaoVoltar}"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="Próximo" icon="proximo" actionListener="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.onNext()}"
                                                 style="float: right" rendered="#{registroOnlineEmpresaController.renderizaBotaoProximo}"/>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="30" footer="© 2019 Todos os direitos reservados." resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

[Link para o Stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/qhHgvN8Q)

Comment: Por que não utilizar o `p:captcha`?

Comment: @nullptr, Esse também apresentou o mesmo problema quando testei

Comment: Teria como postar todo o stack trace para termos mais detalhe do erro?

Comment: Qual versão do JSF e JEE esta usando?

Comment: @MuriloPortugal, editei a pergunta com o stacktrace

Comment: @nullptr, JEE 6 e JSF (Mojarra) 2.1.6

Comment: Se eu botar o recaptcha dentro do h:body, mas fora do p:layout, ele renderiza normalmente

Comment: @JulianaMarques, somente para tirar a dúvida que o problema realmente é no recaptcha, poderia por favor verificar se sem o recaptcha o aviso `Advertência: JSF1090: Caso de navegação não resolvido para o componente j_idt200` ainda aparece no stacktrace?

Comment: @MuriloPortugal, não aparece

Answer (score 1):

Iria colocar como comentário, porém não tenho pontos suficientes...

Um usuário da versão internacional do StackOverFlow, estava com o mesmo problema "Advertência: JSF1090", segue o link da pergunta com a solução -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519776/warning-jsf1090-navigation-case-not-resolved-for-component-j-idt51).

Segundo o autor da resposta com a solução:

"Este aviso ocorrerá sempre que você usar um resultado de navegação (implícito) no atributo de outcome de `<h:link>` ou `<h:button>` , que não representa um ID de exibição válido."

"Além disso, o `<h:link>` renderiza um elemento `<span>` vez de um elemento `<a>` .

A solução é óbvia: use um ID de exibição válido ou certifique-se de que a exibição desejada possa ser resolvida por [ConfigurableNavigationHandler#getNavigationCase()](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?anno=2&depth=1&hl=pt-BR&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&tl=pt-BR&u=http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ConfigurableNavigationHandler.html&xid=17259,15700022,15700186,15700190,15700256,15700259,15700262,15700265&usg=ALkJrhjXpN672b4e0t_36Uh3huKnlAGBWg#getNavigationCase%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Observe que algumas iniciantes usam, por um motivo desconhecido, até mesmo um URL completo como `http://google.com` como valor de resultado de `<h:link>` :

```
<h:link value="Go to Google" outcome="http://google.com" />
```

Esse abuso também produziria exatamente esse aviso. Você deve usar `<h:outputLink>` ou apenas `<a>` .

Quanto à ausência de um elemento HTML com o mesmo ID que o componente JSF, isso pode acontecer quando você não especificou explicitamente o atributo de id do componente JSF. O ID do componente JSF não termina necessariamente na saída HTML gerada. Atribuir a esses componentes um ID fixo deve ajudar melhor na identificação da causa."

Espero ter ajudado.